# Sed script to update links

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I'm new to bash scripts, I wrote this script to go through all my pages of my website to change the link to index from `.html` to `.php`. It does not seem to be working.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=/opt/lampp/htdocs/doLearnFinnace/*
for f in $FILES
do
  echo ;

  # take action on each file. $f store current file name
  if [ -f "$f" ]
  then
      echo "Processing $f file..."
      sed -e 's/"index.html"/"index.php"/g' $f
      cat $f
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sed -e` command in your script just displays the replaced strings on your terminal.

You can use the `-i` option to replace the string "in place" (that is in the files) :

```
sed -i 's/"index.html"/"index.php"/g' $f
```

But this command will replace litterally `"index.html"` in your code, not `'index.html'` nor `path/index.html`

If you want to replace links in your html pages, depending on your links syntax, you may use :

```
sed -i 's/\(href="\/your\/path\/\)index.html"/\1index.php"/g' $f
```

by replacing `\/your\/path\/\` with your real path (escaping the `/` with `\/`)

of with absolute links :

```
sed -i 's/\(href="http:\/\/yourdomain\.com\/your\/path\/\index.html"/\1index.php"/g' $f
```

Moreover, to replace your bash script with a `find` command, you can use :

```
find /opt/lampp/htdocs/doLearnFinnace/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/\(href="\/your\/path\/\)index.html"/\1index.php"/g'
```

It should do the same as your script but without echoing the files during process.

I suggest you make a backup of your website before applying the `sed -i` command, the files will be overwritten without confirmation.

**Update :**

As @Aaron noticed, sed can make for you a backup of each files matched by the sed command using an extension after the `-i` param as `-i.bak`. Just remember to delete these *.bak files from your website after successful replacements.

Comment: Regarding your last sentence, you could suggest the use of `sed -i` with a suffix, i.e. `sed -i.bak` so that files are backed-up before they are edited.

Comment: Ah cool thanks very much . Good to know how to do these thing the popper way. Is that what they call piping. Yes i do have a back up I am just doing  this mostly out of pure interest. I could of went and changed all myself with the amount of time i spent trying to do this script .

Comment: And could you explane why you put the path to the website in the sed comand

Comment: And is the find operation like a loop does it go through each file in the directory.

Comment: Yes, the `find` command is recursive, it looks into current and subfolder from a starting point defined as first parameter (more at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html). Concerning the path in your href, i updaded my answer because it was unclear.